# Project Server 2016 Events

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, project-server, events

We have a Project 2016 server. As it knowns, 2016 has no more PSI support so we have much pain with developing and documentation. The most documentation points to Project 2013 and Online.

The question is about events. So in the General Application Settings there is Server Side Event Handlers:

[image: Adding a new event handler]

For expample I need to catch when a project was updated, so I create a New Event Handler and now I see a field named "Endpoint Url" for providing the WCF Endpoint URL. So how I should deal with it and how could I get the scheme for my proxy class to deal with data that Project Server sends to my WCF service?

[image: Endpoint URL]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out a bit.
You need to create some ServiceHost endpoints either using iis as well with those libs:

```
Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Events;
Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Library;
```

Then you implement interfaces from *Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Events*, for example for resources will be *IResourceEventReceiverRemote*, and use the interface as contract in the endpoint settings. That will be an endpoint for the event handler settings was mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The **Endpoint URL** field is not a mandatory field, you can leave it `blank`. In case you have an on-prem event handler.

But if you have a Remote WCF service `(Remote event Service that will be consumed when a specific Project Event is fired)`, so you should add the `Service Endpoint URL` in this field.

Comment: We need exactly the second one: to send events to remote service so then other system can react to it.And how could I get the scheme for my proxy class to deal with data that Project Server sends to my WCF service?